# Compiling SciPy to Android - Has it been done, any help on how to compile the FORTRAN code to Android Arm

Tags: python, android-ndk, arm, scipy, gfortran

For a project, I am porting a scientific Python app using SciPy to Android. I am currently using

https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android

to build the code. NumPy builds, but SciPy is proving to be a real hassle. Hacking around with devenv, and kivy python for android, I kinda got to compile the SciPy C libs to android ARM, but now, the fortran libs remain to be built, and I'm at a loss.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen [How to build the gcc Fortran cross-compiler for Android (ARM and x86)](http://danilogiulianelli.blogspot.com/2013/02/how-to-build-gcc-fortran-cross-compiler.html), which specifies how to build a cross compiler for fortan for Android and [Running Fortan on ARM](http://panoskrt.wordpress.com/2011/05/15/running-fortran-on-arm/), which mentions the approach of using f2c to convert the fortan to C ?

Comment: You can try using [Dragonegg](http://dragonegg.llvm.org/) to build fortran to LLVM, then use an ARM backend to build it to ARM.
[Compile LLVM to Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665966/is-it-possible-to-compile-llvm-libraries-to-android-arm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few years later, SciPy now builds for arm. Here are some pre-built wheels:
https://forums.resin.io/t/precompiled-python-wheels-for-arm/591

Answer (score 1):

An apology if this is a non-answer:

First off, if you are just playing around I recommend installing a regular linux on arm chroot jail/environment, e.g. raspbian or ubuntu and working within.

Finally if you want to build your libs as proper android libs, you have to deal with slightly different runtime, but that has been done, at least wrt. Fortran.
http://specificimpulses.blogspot.com/2011/01/my-android-speaks-fortran-yours-can-too.html

Typically you are expected to cross-compile, however there are way to get Adnroid sortof self-hosted (gcc, build tools), but I can't vouch for ability to pip install packages that require compilation.

Answer (score 1):

We were able to use Linux-deploy to install a (mostly) fully featured Ubuntu on an Android device.
We were able to install Python with SciPy NumPy ...etc.

BTW: by installing with optimizations for arm we were able to reach better performance than x86 cpu ( with a good fan to cool down the computer ).

Comment: Yes, the question is 4 years old, scipy has been built for arm now